# Is it possible to send Images to an Express API with SvelteKit `on:change` using Form Actions?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, svelte, sveltekit

I have an SvelteKit app which communicates with an Express API to save user's data.

I have a form with an input file, and I am sending the image to my Express server using Form Actions.

The problem is that I have a button to save the image, and it only gets saved when clicking the button. So, the user has to change the image, and then click on the button to save it.

To improve user experience, I want to save the image `on:change`, but I don't know how to do that with Form Actions.

Any ideas?

Here is my simple component:

```
<div>
    <label for="avatar">
            <img src="/avatar.svg" alt="avatar" />

        <span>Cambiar foto</span>
    </label>
    <input type="file" id="avatar" name="avatar" accept=".jpg,.jpeg,.png,.webp,.avif" />
</div>

<BtnMain>Guardar</BtnMain>
```

Here is the action of my `+page.server.js`:

```
export const actions = {
    update: async ({ request }) => {
        const formData = await request.formData();

        const res = await fetch(url, {
            method: 'POST',
            credentials: 'include',
            body: formData
        });
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

In your +page.server.js, add the following lines:

```js
export const actions = {
    update: async ({ request }) => {
        const formData = await request.formData();
        try {
            const res = await fetch(url, {
                method: 'POST',
                credentials: 'include',
                body: formData
            });
            if(res.ok)
                return { success : true }
        } catch (error) {
            return fail(422, {
                description: 'I failed so hard',
                error: error.message
        });
    }
}
```

Now in +page.svelte, where your form actually is, do something of the like

```html
<script>
//'form' is a bit like sveltekit's 'data', a special getter on client-side
//allowing you to easily obtain server data, in this case, form related stuff 
/** @type {import('./$types').ActionData} */
export let form;

let imageReady = false;
</script>

<form
        method="POST"
        action="?/update"
        use:enhance={() => {
            return async ({ result }) => {
                if (result.data.success} {
                    imageReady = true;
                    //Implement your logic here to trigger download for instance
                }
            };
        }}
    >
```

What's happening here is use:enhance will return a callback triggered from the return function of the action on +page.server.js, this allows you to do server stuff while keeping the client page alive before getting a response from the server. Very neat feature of svelte-kit.
There's some caveats, read more on [sveltekit doc](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/form-actions#loading-data)